# Is there a way to require initial authentication before reading Minidriver containers?

Tags: smartcard, cng

I'm developing a Minidriver for a smartcard that requires card access number (CAN, printed on a card to prevent contactless skimming of the data) to read the public data (certificates) on it. The usual workflow with this card is:

1. CAN authentication
2. Reading of PKCS#15 file structures and certificates
3. PIN authentication
4. Signature operation

In PKCS#11 library this can be achieved by using `CKF_LOGIN_REQUIRED` token flag.

But `certutil -scinfo` utility (which I use for testing the Minidriver) seems to try to get container information before any authentication is performed (it calls `CardGetContainerInfo`) and then fails when Minidriver doesn't return any containers (with `NTE_BAD_KEYSET`).

Is there a way to indicate to CAPI application that it should login before trying to read any information from the card (maybe in `CONTAINER_MAP_RECORD` or `PIN_INFO` structures)?